# PHP post facebook page statuses

Tags: php

```
$data  = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/124292684247609/feed?access_token=MY TOKEN");
$data = json_decode($data, true);

print_r($data);
```

That's the code I've tried, since no others work. But this does neither, but still gives me no major errors. But it doesn't post facebook posts, for some reasons.

How can I post a facebook groups statuses/posts?

Edit: I cannot use the array at all

Comment: Does that link work when pasted in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

```
$data  = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/(Page-Id)/feed?message=Hello&access_token=MY TOKEN");
$data = json_decode($data, true);

print_r($data);
```

you can easily post like this.

you will need permission publish_action,manage_pages;

Answer (score -1):

```
$posts = $data->data;
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    if (isset($post->id)) {
        $post->id;
        $message = (isset($post->message) ? mysql_real_escape_string($post->message) : '');
        echo $post_id.' '.$message;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't output anything

Comment: You have to paste it in a browser to see if you are getting anything.

Comment: file_put_contents('feed.json', $data); # add this line after the file_get_contents and open it with notepad to check its contents.

Comment: I do, and when I use foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
   echo $val;
} it simply outputs "ArrayArray"

Comment: What the heck is `mysql_real_escape_string` doing in this? It's a) deprecated and b) doesn't make sense.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string cleans the input in order to be insert into a database. I should have erase that function.

Comment: Can you try foreach ($data->data as $key => $val)

Comment: $data->data as $key => $val doesn't work, gives no output

Comment: Then you have no choice but to view the contents in notepad of the JSON file saved from Facebook in order to analyze it. Maybe it has an error message.

Comment: The below is how I construct my URL. Of course I should have a valid token. $page_facebookid is the page's ID, $since and $until define the month.

    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$page_facebookid.'/feed';
    $url .= "?since=$since&until=$until";
    $url .= "&limit=50";
    $url .= "&access_token=$token";